# How can I set the text of a textarea element with Jade without whitespace?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

Currently I have a solution that works perfectly for me:

```
textarea.
    #{myObject.myVar}
```

However I get the following warning from Jade when compiling the file

> Cannot read property 'myVar' of undefined

This is understandable, because `myObject` might not exist when loading this template.
So I've tried something like the following which also works without Jade errors, but I end up with leading and trailing whitespace in the `textarea` element.

```
textarea
    if myObject && myObject.myVar
        = myObject.myVar
```

How can I combine these two solutions to omit leading/trailing whitespace in the `textarea` element, while also making Jade compile the file without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
textarea=myObject ? myObject.myVar : ''
```